# Why my program automatically frees things?

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to do a program for a university task and I'm receiving this message from Valgrind:

```
==4244== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4244==     in use at exit: 300 bytes in 2 blocks
==4244==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 3 frees, 2,428 bytes allocate
```

I don't know where this **3 frees** comes from because **when I erased all of my free functions these 3 stayed there**. I thought that when a function returns without freeing things, that'd be a case of memory leak.

My question is: **why it isn't?** Does a function frees everything declared in it when it returns? If so, how do I know that a function is successfully freeing the stuff declared in there?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know if I totally understood what did you say... If I called malloc three times and freed the 3 allocated things, why is it an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff gets malloc()ed and free()ed in code outside of your source, such as library functions. Valgrind sees all of that.

Comment: But why some stuff get free()ed while others doesn't?

Comment: @HenriqueQ.dosSantos Depends on the stuff. Note specifying "--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all" to valgrind will get it to print the functions that called `malloc` for all the memory that was not later freed.

Comment: Library functions don't always free stuff. It's pretty harmless if the memory only gets allocated the once and gets used for the entire life of the program. Library functions that created structures and copied them without initializing the space between the values were the bane of my valgrind life. A few one off malloc()s are easy to ignore.

Comment: I get it. Thanks @aschepler for helping! I'm still learning how to use Valgrind.

Comment: @HenriqueQ.dosSantos: if the answer was helpful for you, please click the checkmark icon next to it to mark it as solved. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).